# Fixing Tabbing Controls in HTML Always Showing at the Bottom Edge of the Screen

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm working on an audit site for the company I work for. We want to be able to show questions on a single VERY long page, with the options Yes/No/NA as radio buttons beside each question.

We have the questions and the controls loading properly, but we want users to be able to tab through the questions and answer them rapidly. The problem with this is that when tabbing, it shows the radio button that's been tabbed to at the very bottom edge of the page.

I've searched online for a solution, but haven't had much luck locating one as every time you mention tab and HTML together, Google thinks that you mean opening a new tab or showing tabs on your HTML page.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I've tried adding padding to the bottom of my radio button controls, but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: try searching for css tabindex

Comment: Will that actually affect how it shows on the screen? I've got tabindex set, but I can't see the question that's being answered because it's hidden under the footer while tabbing. I just want to make it so that when you tab, it brings it up above where the footer is so that you can read the question and see the answer you're giving. It tabs through the controls just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed Javascript, not HTML/CSS. Using the solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837369/input-on-focus-or-tab-key-pressed-move-to-center-of-screen), I was able to make it so that it keeps scrolling when tabbing through the controls. I specifically used the following code.

```
$(':input').focus(function () {
         var center = $(window).height() / 2;
         var top = $(this).offset().top;
         if (top > center) {
             $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top - center }, 'fast');            
         }
     });
```